# How to extract records from Dstream and write into Cassandra (Spark Streaming)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am fetching data from Kafka and processing in Spark Streaming and writing Data into Cassandra

I am trying to Filter the DStream records but it doesn't filter the records and write the complete records in Cassandra,

**Any suggestion with sample/example Code to filter multiple columns of records and any help will be highly appreciated** i have done a research on this but not able to get any solution.

```
class SparkKafkaConsumer1(val recordStream : org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String], val streaming : StreamingContext) {

val internationalAddress = recordStream.map(line => line.split("\\|")(10).toUpperCase)

def timeToStr(epochMillis: Long): String =
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMddHHmmss").print(epochMillis)

if(internationalAddress =="INDIA")
{
print("-----------------------------------------------")
recordStream.print()
val riskScore = "1"
val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
val formatedTimeStamp = timeToStr(timestamp)
var wc1 = recordStream.map(_.split("\\|")).map(r=>Row(r(0),r(1),r(2),r(3),r(4).toInt,r(5).toInt,r(6).toInt,r(7),r(8),r(9),r(10),r(11),r(12),r(13),r(14),r(15),r(16),riskScore.toInt,0,0,0,formatedTimeStamp))
implicit val rowWriter = SqlRowWriter.Factory
wc1.saveToCassandra("fraud", "fraudrating", SomeColumns("purchasetimestamp","sessionid","productdetails","emailid","productprice","itemcount","totalprice","itemtype","luxaryitem","shippingaddress","country","bank","typeofcard","creditordebitcardnumber","contactdetails","multipleitem","ipaddress","consumer1score","consumer2score","consumer3score","consumer4score","recordedtimestamp"))

}
```

(Note: I am have records with internationalAddress = INDIA in Kafka and I am very much new to Scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but if you are simply trying to filter on records pertaining to India, you could do this:

```
implicit val rowWriter = SqlRowWriter.Factory
recordStream
   .filter(_.split("\\|")(10).toUpperCase) == "INDIA")
   .map(_.split("\\|"))
   .map(r => Row(...))
   .saveToCassandra(...)
```

As a side note, I think [case classes](http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-case-classes-in-depth/) would be really helpful for you.